# How to use keyboard to go back to the Google Search box

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

As I need to constantly search with Google engine, and it annoys me really when every time I have to use the mouse to click in the search box to key in the next search key words. Is there an easier way to do this without switching back and forth between mouse and keyboard? I use Google Chrome and know I can do search with the omnibar, but I prefer to activate the search box on the page since it's quicker.

Answer (score 6):

Either press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and type <kbd>?</kbd>, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: I discover Ctrl k will put the focus into the address bar,and that is not inside the search box, and it looks complicated, can focus on search box directly and be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

Just type on after you are done with the previous search. It will directly go to the search bar.

Google makes everything easy to use buddy.

Comment: This is the correct anwer, wow stack exchange suffers the halo effect.